# OnLocationResult of fused Location api is only called once even when i have requested updates in given time interval in android

Tags: java, android, google-api, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I have read a few questions and answers related to this , but none has solved my problem. Please suggest me what should i do. I am using this fused location api in my android background service. And i have provided all the nougat/marshmellow checks also. But i get result location only once or first time, after that , the onLocation result is not called, is it so that only when i change my location it will be called ? please help

heres my simple onCreate of service:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        fusedLocationProviderClient= LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(4000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(4000);

        locationCallback=new LocationCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                Log.i("serviceTag","onLocationResult called");
               }


            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            }



    }
```

Comment: You claim you read some related Q&A; you should link them, and state why they didn't help.

Comment: It was working last night properly, giving updates , i just dont know what happened today. Updates have stopped. And in other questions, answers arent matching my criteria, for example  ppl have missed few varibles or some one has suggested to use something else, my simple point is , what is the problem in this updates using same fused api. Edit: i forgot to add setpriotity in location request btw.

Comment: @Maximus what happened did you got the issue.

Answer (score 1):

FusedLocationProviderClient provides location updates only in foregrounded state either when an Activity (any not necessarily the one requesting or using location updates) is resumed or when a foreground service associated with location foregroundServiceType is started.

From Android 10, framework developers most likely choose to sub categorize foreground services by a type to ensure not all apps with generic foreground services like media apps gets free access to locations when backgrounded. Given that, it is trivial for application developers to just add this “location” type in manifest for unrelated foreground service to work around the limitation.

https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/android-foregroundservicetype-8857a36f36b9

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to figure this out for many hours. It was ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in my case. However I did not think to check permissions.